# aaabbabbc⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Tags: code-golf, string

One element of the list `aa, ab, ba, bb, c` has been removed, and the remainder shuffled and joined with no separator. Find the missing element.

For example, if the input was `aaabbac`, this is made by concatenating `aa ab ba c`, so the output would be `bb`.

### Rules

- Standard I/O rules apply.
- You must take input as a string (or equivalent in your language), and you must use the characters `abc` as in the question; you cannot substitute them for others.
- This is code golf, shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
cbbbaab  -> aa
bbbaabc  -> aa
cabbabb  -> aa
baaacbb  -> ab
bbcaaba  -> ab
caababb  -> ab
bbcabaa  -> ba
abcaabb  -> ba
abcbbaa  -> ba
bacaaab  -> bb
aacabba  -> bb
caaabba  -> bb
bbabaaba -> c
aaabbabb -> c
abaabbba -> c
```

Comment: So a list of characters isn't allowed if there is a string type? Just making sure

Comment: Is printing `"c "` instead of `"c"` okay?

Comment: @noodleman correct

Comment: @Lynn I think I'll insist the output/return value should be exactly `c`

Comment: Can we input the list of elements as well as the string to be tested

Comment: @Graham No, you may not

Answer (score 30):

## [Python](https://www.python.org),  <s>55</s>  51 bytes

```python
lambda a:'%x'%(-int(a.replace('c','0c'),16)%255-39)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBfisIwEIfZR3OKkKUkgVZcRVkFvYj6MDO1GKi1dCvoWXwpyO6d3NPsNGmp-xQ-vt9k_tx_ylt9PBfNI1vvvi91lnw-ZzmcMAUJKx1ddWQSV9QGxtWhzIEORpOO9YS0jT8WNprO58lsaUPp79t7ulZKESICoJTJRgKIQNQjATMOFgCoR-QwcRh69PDfcoFHBAE-jC-ILxaBbTcGouA2becevRuwnck3ZiQRHP8cqDXYOd5v_FXmrjZqVygrsnMlnXSFTFdiVFbtsTLjuojdTvY2lgNO992tmia8fw)

Explain:

- Observe that 'a', 'b', 'c' are base 16 digits.
- I learnt from Albert.Lang's solution that we can use int(a.replace('c',''),x)%(x*x-1) to extract sum of character at odd and even position.
- Replace 'c' with '0c' allow us to subtract by 39 to get 'c' without affecting other output cases (Original idea is to replace 'c' with '33', by xnor).
- Finally, '%x'% is used to convert int back to base 16.

Logs:

- Saved 4 bytes thank to xnor's suggests.

## [Python](https://www.python.org),  <s>94</s> 92 bytes

```python
lambda a:('c'in a)*''.join(chr(390-sum(map(ord,a.replace('c','')[i::2])))for i in(0,1))or'c'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDBToQwEIbj0T5FUw9tDRBcL0qyvgiLyUxZsjVQSJc9-CxeSIy-kz6NQwthPTVfvr_9p_PxPbyPp95Nn83-8HUZm_Tp57WFDmvgUChppHUc9L2U2VtvnSrNyavH5zw9XzrVwaB6XyeQ-ePQgjnO-URKXdqi2FVa66b33HK6lycPutK9p0Bs-b25q_dCCIOIAMh5-sIBWCSzogFi3CwAmBWRwobCsGKA_5YuBERgEMJ4hXhlEcguYyAyqpmbVwxuw3mmUExoWHT0cqTZ4OLof9l5aO2oxMEJzdZ18Lpgt4O3blSNsktEl3mlE74hbTDuapri-Qc)

Logs:

- Saved 2 bytes thank to Jonathan Allan's tip.

Comment: Very nice. You can remove the `[]` to `join` generated results.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBNasMwEEbpsjqFUDGSwA6JaUIIpBdpsvhGjonAdYzjQnuWbgylvVN7mo4lG6cr8XjfaH4-vpv37nyp-89yf_h67cps-7Op8EIFJHY6edOJyZePma87g0V7aiq4k9FOp1rbdLWxSb5eX1q5ym2s_r17KPZKKUdEAEmZPUlARHITOjDTbAG4CYnDjsOYMMB_ywUBCQIhTDdIN5bAdhyDSHCbofOEwc04zBQaMzoRHf8caTA0Ot5vcW0q3xl1qJUVJV_AS1_LYifum3Y4Vmn8GLHPy6NN5Yz5cbxV38f3Dw)

Comment: [Maybe there's something](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBNasMwEEbpMjqFUDGSwA5pQkIJpBdpsvhGjqnAdYzjQnKWbgyhvVN7mo4lG6cr8XjfaH4-v-tr-3aqulux2399tEX2_LMo8U45JLY6uejEZL5qDebNsS7hjkY7nerVStv0aWOT5XptY93vw2O-U0o5IgJIyuxFAiKSG9GBmSYLwI1IHHYcxogB_lsuCEgQCGG6Q7qzBLbDGESC2_SdRwxuwn6m0JjRiej450i9ocHxfvNzXfrWqH2lrChOjfTSVzLfilnd9JcqjB8i9nVxsKmccHkYbtV18f0D) with `int(a.replace('c','33'))` if you can find a decent way to handle the `c` output case.

Comment: Ty, found out we can do int(a.replace('c','0c')) so we subtract by 39 to get 'c' without affecting other output cases. I will edit the answer.

Comment: IMHO `(216-int(a.replace('c','0c'),16)%255)` is more readable than `(-int(a.replace('c','0c'),16)%255-39)`.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for pointing out. I thought about that and finally decided to stick with my version that's closer to suggests in comments. I did think about putting both versions but eventually forgot =='

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```javascript
s=>(s+"aaabbabbc").replace(q=/c|../g,s=>(q[s]^=1)?o=s:0)&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7BTsMwDL3vK0wOq6O2GVw3ZdMO3HefxpSGtCsKTdaUXYA/QOLCEf6D79kP8AnFCZqEZD372X7PflAnFXTf@qHs3L0ZazkGucSQM6VUVVFoxkVvvFXa4FHO9IsQs6aIS8dt2N3JG75yMsyv@XTqRmsGWIOELZCeFYRVxCrVVao1g91iMlmL2vW3Sh8QfQEdB7mE5wlAdLBtGKLJroANZVQFeMqMpS0lrOma4QArKh@VRzwV0KbRBpWoWzuYHveRt2XJozaHE@eECubJXPincEDPF3Rwg@uLBvcXoxauJD2VFpLg8myIU@264KwR1jXUyIFBuSTIocbAE48EE5OS7q8g@/l@P39@EGb0Q3b@esv4n/1/M2q88vEX)

### Commented

```javascript
s =>              // s = input string
(s + "aaabbabbc") // append all the patterns to s
.replace(         // replace:
  q =             //   we use q as an object to keep track of
                  //   encountered patterns
  /c|../g,        //   a pattern is either 'c' or 2 characters
  s =>            //   for each matched pattern s:
    (q[s] ^= 1) ? //     if this is the first time we see it:
      o = s       //       save it into o
    :             //     else:
      0           //       do nothing
) && o            // end of replace(); return o (i.e. the last
                  // pattern seen for the first time)
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

Porting [Phan Trọng Nhân's excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266576/58563) is definitely shorter.

```javascript
s=>(216-`0x${s}`.replace('c','0c')%255).toString(16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7BSgMxEL3vV4yLkgndDW2hPVjS0oP3gkcpbTZm20jcDZtYhNI/ELx41P/we/oDfsKaRApe3rw3M@/NPImDcLLT1pdN@6j6mveOz3E8mpbb4ev10Z22rFPWCKmQSFKQoST0ZjyZUObbe9/pZoejKe2N8rAEDg@QC5EXAauIVeJV4jKH9SzLlqxuuzsh94i2gIYCn8MxA4gJRjsfQ9YFrEJFUYANNc/TlmBGNTu/h0Wgz8IiHgrQabRCwWptvOpwE7UuSxq9AzhQGlDAbQpn9sXt0dJZOLjC5cWDm0uQhisenkoLyXB51sWpbBvXGsVMuwuNAeRQzgMMoEZHk44Ck@I83F8A@fl@P39@BCThB3L@eiP0L/5/WGicaP8L)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

My original answer.

```javascript
s=>"b__c__aab"[q=s.replace(/c|../g,s=>'0x'+s|0)%9]+["ab"[q%7%5]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BTsMwELz3FYulKraSuL0gBJVb9cC99yqKNsZpg0xi4lAhUX6AxIUj/IP39AM8IayNKnGZ3dmdmd17PKDXfeOGvO3uzFir0aslq8pSlyVixbaPysveOIva8Jk@SjnbZSRJ5s9J6o9zMb0u0i2LyunV9LIoRmsGWIOCLTBElkFYElaxr2KvGRSLyWQt666/Rb3n3GXQClBLeJkAhATb@CGEFBlsqHLMwFFlLKpQWtPuhj2sqH1Ax/khgyauNhxl3djB9LwMvMlzEbwpHIQgRLiJ4dI9@T13YkEHN3x99vDyHNTAhaKnoiAazs/6sNVd6ztrpO12NEiBQb4kSKHmXkQeCI9MKbq/guTn@/30@UGY0A/J6estEX/x/8No8CrGXw)

### How?

#### Identifying the missing pattern

We look for the relevant patterns in the input string with `/c|../g` and replace each of them with its decimal value when parsed as hexadecimal.

This gives:

| original pattern | replaced with |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 170 |
| ab | 171 |
| ba | 186 |
| bb | 187 |
| c | 12 |

For instance, `"abbabbc"` is turned into `"17118618712"`.

It is a well known fact that \$n \bmod 9\$ is the sum of the decimal digits of \$n\$ modulo \$9\$. (Obviously, the order of the digits doesn't matter.)

Because each decimal pattern described above has a different remainder modulo \$9\$, we can identify the missing one by just reducing the entire transformed string modulo \$9\$:

| \$q=n \bmod 9\$ | missing pattern |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ba |
| 3 | c |
| 6 | ab |
| 7 | aa |
| 8 | bb |

#### Output

We use a 9-character lookup string for the first character:

```javascript
"b__c__aab"[q=...]
```

We could also use the following trick, which is unfortunately just as long:

```javascript
"bac"[7/(q=...)|0]
```

And we use a shorter lookup string with a modulo chain for the 2nd character, wrapped into brackets so that *undefined* is turned into an empty string for \$q=3\$:

```javascript
["ab"[q%7%5]]
```

Answer (score 15):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ù¢╓┘0ï<ΣEZ1
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=979bd6d9308b3ce4455a31&i=%22cbbbaab%22&a=1)

Unpacked (13 bytes):

```
'c|^2/M{{SkmT
```

Explanations:

```
'c|^         Set xor with "c" without deduplication or changing of order.
2/           Split into 2 character chunks.
M            Transpose (aka zip).
{{Skm        Map by reduce by xor of the character codes.
             The two lines work like reducing by vectorized xor.
T            Trim on the right. For some reasons null bytes are also
             printed as spaces and are also removed.
```

<del>The difficult part is to find the right language that had all the required features.</del> Many languages have them but they may not be the default behavior of the most obvious operator, so I thought they don't. The most important one is set xor (set symmetric difference) without deduplication. Others are splitting to equally sized chunks, and doing mathematics on character values. But Stax doesn't have map and reduce operators with block starters omitted for a single character operation.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 87 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), <del>11</del> 10.875 bytes

```
\cÞ⊍C2ẇƒ꘍C∑Ǎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFxjw57iio1DMuG6h8aS6piNQ+KIkceNIiwiIiwiY2JiYmFhYiJd)

Bitstring:

```
011010100001110110101010000101011001101011111101101001000110111010111001101110101010000
```

Explanations:

```
\cÞ⊍         Set xor with "c" without deduplication or changing of order.
C            Convert characters to numbers.
2ẇ           Split into 2 character chunks.
ƒ꘍           Reduce by automatically vectorized xor.
C            Convert back to characters.
∑            Concatenate.
Ǎ            Remove non-letters, i.e. the null byte if the answer is "c".
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
ḟ”cQp`ḟs2$Ʋȯ”c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xCsJAEEX7PUUKWxvbgHewtPP/wUZSCFZ2wSbgGRTBWhCCRSBlIHiN3Yuss5ssid2@fX/mz2FfFGfvbfNw5V02x52@TqtFX3/f4cPnrrxly3WmkHeVse3HNrVtnl3VX93ltfVeSALMQgowA0lCgTInC0ASUsOiYSSM8G91ICJhEMOcIWeWUDueQRqtCc0Jo5sw3BSLFcUMTjcPFAxH9wM)

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!*

A full program taking a string as its argument and printing the missing piece. (It can also be used as a monadic link, but will return a Jelly string if the result is one of the `ab` permutations and a single character for `c`.)

### Explanation

```
ḟ”cQp`ḟs2$Ʋȯ”c
ḟ”c            | Filter out "c"
         Ʋ     | Following as a monad:
  Q            | - Uniquify
   p`          | - Cartesian product with itself
     ḟ         | - Filter out
      s2$      |   - The c-less input split into twos
           ȯ”c | Or "c"
```

### Alternative approach: [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
œ^”cs2œ^"/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY6xCsIwFEX3fEVwF8G14H@4CPc@XKSbk1txKbi66uLsJA4Fx1L/I/mR@JI0tG45Ofe9@w77uj6FMFx3vrnLca2PxSpUvrnZ5cbqX9W3xn3ernu57tG334s/P7chCEmANqYAk0kKCpQ5WQBSkBoWDaNggn@rAwkJgxTmDDmzhNrxDNJoTWwumNyE8aZUrCgmO92cKRqO7gc)

This is a translation of [@jimmy23013’s clever Stax answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266596/42248); I’ve not replaced my main one since I wanted to preserve my different approach, but this is clearly shorter!

`œ^”cŒœœ^/€` would also work for ten.

Comment: Ah, smart using a Cartesian product to get valid non-c pairs. ``ḟ”cQp`ḟs2$Ʋȯ”c`` saves a byte.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 55 bytes

```python
lambda a:f'{int("cc"+(30*a).strip("ab"),16)%255%192:x}'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU5LisJAFNznFI8GsTv2BD9EnUBvPIebl9bGFvtD5wUyDHOBuYKbgDh3mtv4iW6qKOpDnf_iFx2C7y9Gba8tmY_1_-qErt4hYGXG39YTZ1qzCV9McxRFQ8lGzrBmQs6WYjQvy9Hsc151P-NX_de6GBKBpX2iEE4NYHMX2QYUMM1kznFSgwkJUNZg_d0rYgq7VtNzVz7HRfZIOJnrd2SfXEtINviGb0SVAcT0eNdVirHiGKznWkjDuwGUcmJ41PcD3wA)

This produces 15 (= base - 1) on frame and (if `c` is present) 15 off frame copies of the input. The sum will therefore be 0 modulo 0x11 x 0x0f. `.strip("ab")` removes one set of on frame copies of all but c. Adding 0xcc which is the sum of the four possible non c terms mod 0xff yields the missing item unless it is c which is dealt with separately.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:" aabbcbaba"[int(s.replace("c",""),14)%195%8::5]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU5LasMwFNz7FI8HASlVDYEGEoE2uUabxZNiUxXrg_QM6RV6hWwMIb1Tb1Mbt5sZhvkwt-_8ye8pTvfevD1G7p8PP8eBgr0QVI1AZK2zZAlffWRR29LlgVwn0KFClGr3Ije7435z0Hp__hv48iGnwuC5K5zSUIHqLJoTGFh6W0FPFvpUgJQFH2evzSVdRscCyc7DM0jZLImgtu4_0pUwMrFPsYqT1A1ALsurqzaI7UfyUTipenFdwZgg10fTtPIv)

#### How?

First get rid of the evil frame-shifting "c". Afterwards read as base 14 and add all pairs by reducing modulo 195. Further reduce and produce the answer by indexing into a magic string.

Comment: This is certainly shorter than anything I was trying! I'll post a bounty when the question is old enough to allow it.

Comment: @xnor Obviously, I'm waiving the promised bounty now that I've myself been outgolfed so comprehensively.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 106 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 13.25 bytes

```
‛ab2↔\cpṖ'ḣ∑?=;hh
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oCbYWIy4oaUXFxjcOG5lifhuKPiiJE/PTtoaCIsIiIsImFiYWFiYmJhIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
1010100100110111101010010101000011000010000011011100110001101010100111101011100111001010011100110100101110
```

### Explained

```
«F^ǒ⇩v«2ẇṖ'ḣ∑?=;hh­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
         Ṗ          # ‎⁡Permutations of
«F^ǒ⇩v«             # ‎⁢The string "aaabbabbc"
       2ẇ           # ‎⁣split into chunks of size 2
          '    ;    # ‎⁤Filtered by:
           ḣ        # ‎⁢⁡  the permutation with the head removed
            ∑       # ‎⁢⁢  joined into a single string
             ?=     # ‎⁢⁣  equals the input.
                hh  # ‎⁢⁤Get the first item of the first item in that list.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: You can replace the compressed string with a hardcoded version for [106 bits](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oCbYWIy4oaUXFxjcOG5lifhuKPiiJE/PTtoaCIsIiIsImFiYWFiYmJhIl0=).

Answer (score 6):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com) 9.4, 25 bytes

```
(]>.&XOR&.dfh _2]\-.)&'c'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNbRc3DwVbK4WUtAwFKz2FjLQULiU99TSQkLqCjoKBghUQ6-opOAf5uC0tLUnTtdipEWunpxbhH6SmB9IbbxQbo6unqaaerA6Rv8XIrsmVmpyRr5CmoJ6clJSUmJikDheA8JMRAsmJQJEkoAqEksTExOQkFD3JQD2JyHoS0fUAlQD1IZQkgvUkoQgkgVUg2QNUguw2oLUgx6DYAxFAsgdkDbIaiBJUm0BCQDWQ8FiwAEIDAA)

`dfh` and `hfd` were [recently modified](https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource/blame/32cb7235527fe9132c76a0c054c3992a5fb05975/jlibrary/system/main/stdlib.ijs#L252) to have each other as inverses. ATO doesn't have the change yet.

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 26 bytes

```
12(hfd@>.XOR)_2 dfh\-.&'c'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxy9BIIyMtxcFOL8I_SDPeSCElLSNGV09NPVkdouAWI7smV2pyRr5CmoJ6clJSUmJikjpcAMJPRggkJwJFkoAqEEoSExOTk1D0JAP1JCLrSUTXA1QC1IdQkgjWk4QikARWgWQPUAmy24DWghyDYg9EAMkekDXIaiBKUG0CCQHVQMJjwQIIDQA)

The XOR of three of `aa, ab, ba, bb` interpreted as hexadecimal (or any base that is a greater power of 2) is the missing one, and the XOR of all four is zero. When all four are present, the XOR value is replaced with 12 before converting back to hexadecimal.

```
12(hfd@>.XOR)_2 dfh\-.&'c'    input: a string
                    -.&'c'    remove 'c'
             _2 dfh\          convert each chunk of 2 with "hex->int"
  (      XOR)                 reduce by bitwise XOR
12     >.                     max with 12; if the result is 0, use 12 instead
   hfd@                       convert with "int->hex"
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 99 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 12.375 bytes

```
\co2ẇHƒ꘍12∴k6τ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIlxcY28y4bqHSMaS6piNMTLiiLRrNs+EIiwiIiwiY2JiYmFhYlxuY2FhYmFiYlxuYWJjYmJhYVxuYmFjYWFhYlxuYWJhYWJiYmEiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
011010100001111110010011010110100010110000110101011111111011101001101110100010100100100101011011010
```

Literal translation of the J solution above.

```
\co2ẇHƒ꘍12∴k6τ
\co               remove 'c'
   2ẇ             chunks of 2
     H            convert each with "hex->int"
      ƒ꘍          reduce by bitwise XOR
        12∴      max with 12
            k6τ   into base "lower hex digits"; convert with "int->hex"
```

Comment: This is excellent.

Comment: `(](>.XOR)&.dfh _2]\-.)&'c'` also for 26, but for some reason fails on ATO though it works locally 9.4.2.

Comment: @Jonah That's because `dfh` and `hfd` were [recently modified](https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource/blame/32cb7235527fe9132c76a0c054c3992a5fb05975/jlibrary/system/main/stdlib.ijs#L252) to have each other as inverses. ATO version is presumably older than that.

Comment: I see you managed to shave off another byte from my suggestion by using `&` on the XOR part too, since it has no effect on single values -- clever!

Answer (score 5):

## [TypeScript](https://typescriptlang.org/)'s Type System, <s>144</s> 142 bytes

```typescript
type F<S,X=0>=S extends`c${infer R}`?F<R,X|"c">:S extends`${infer A}${infer B}${infer R}`?F<R,X|`${A}${B}`>:Exclude<"aa"|"ab"|"ba"|"bb"|"c",X>
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAZQDQA0C8AGAfGhUIAewEAdgCYDOABgMYAkA3gJYkBmEATlAEoC+VAfnjdUAHwBENcVgBceQsXLVGLdlwCCvFW05QAQluY6ufQcLFVGmxgaqyAogRoAbAK5kIccQENv4id4ARv7igX4SgcESUqhYALAAUImgkFDEFMAAjFBosF6+QWGR0okA9KVQlQB6Asng0OnAAEw5eZKFhSUJ5ZVQNXWpjQDMrfA+gTS+xfHdFdW1CUA)

This is only so long because it has to check for "c" separately because TypeScript annoyingly doesn't let you `infer` part of a string that is a union of strings of variable length. I also have a different idea that might be shorter, but it's not at all obvious how to accomplish it in TS types so it might take me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20 18</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-p%5Bage)

-3 thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy) reminding me to golf the magic table.

```
⁾abp`”cṭŒ!F=¥Þ⁸ṪṪ
```

A full program that accepts the flattened, redacted permutation and prints the missing item.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R477EpIKERw1zkx/uXHt0kqKb7aGlh@c9atzxcOcqIPr//79SUlJyYlJiohIA)** Or see all twenty four of each of the five choices [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R477EpIKERw1zkx/uXHt0kqKb7aGlh@c9atzxcOcqIPr/qGFOYmJiUhIQJQNVFRsdnZxscmgrSOWjpjWH24GEt2bkfwA).

##### How?

Brute force...

```
⁾abp`”cṭŒ!F=¥Þ⁸ṪṪ - Link: list of characters, X
⁾ab               - "ab"
   p`             - Cartesian product with itself -> ["aa","ab","ba","bb"]
     ”cṭ          - tack 'c' character -> ["ab","ba","bb","aa",'c']
        Œ!        - all permutations
             Þ    - sort by:
            ¥ ⁸   -   last two links as a dyad - f(Permutation, X):
          F       -     flatten the Permutation
           =      -     equals X (vectorised)
               Ṫ  - tail -> permutation with matching prefix
                Ṫ - tail -> the missing pair
                  - implicit print
```

---

#### Non-brute-force 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-p%5Bage)

I quite like this non-brute force method at **21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-p%5Bage)** though (maybe it can be improved upon?)...

```
ḟ”cOḤÐoS;Ḥ$%5Qị“bbaac
```

A full program that accepts the flattened, redacted permutation and prints the missing item.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmPGuYm@z/cseTwhPxgayCtomoa@HB396OGOUlJiYnJ////V0pKSk4EspUA)** Or see all twenty four of each of the five choices [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmPGuYm@z/cseTwhPxgayCtomoa@HB396OGOUlJiYnJ/4HyD3dOO7SECyiSmJgIFExKSgYKFhsdnZxscmjr0UmKbo@a1hxuBxKa7v//KwEVJSclJSkBAA).

##### How?

```
ḟ”cOḤÐoS;Ḥ$%5Qị“bbaac - Main Link: list of characters
ḟ”c                   - remove any 'c' character
   O                  - cast to ordinal values ('a' -> 97, 'b' -> 98)
     Ðo               - apply to odd indices (first, third, ...):
    Ḥ                 -   double
       S              - sum
        ;Ḥ$           - concatenate double this value -> [sum, 2×sum]
           %5         - modulo five -> [sum%5, (2×sum)%5]
             Q        - deduplicate
              ị“bbaac - index into "bbaac"
```

##### Examples:

**1. missing "c"** `"aaabbbba"`

-> `"aaabbbba"` (removed `'c'`; no change)
-> `[97,97,97,98,98,98,98,97]` (cast to ordinals)
-> `[194,97,194,98,196,98,194,97]` (double values at odd indices)
-> `1170` (sum those)
-> `[1170, 2340]` (concatenate double itself)
-> `[0, 0]` (modulo five)
-> `[0]` (deduplicate)
-> `"c"` (index into "bbaac" - Note that indexing is one-based and modular)

**2. missing "bb"** `"aaacbba"`

-> `"aaabba"` (removed `'c'`)
-> `[97,97,97,98,98,97]` (cast to ordinals)
-> `[194,97,194,98,196,97]` (double values at odd indices)
-> `876` (sum those - i.e. \$1170 - (2 \times 98) - 98 = 876\$)
-> `[876, 1752]` (concatenate double itself)
-> `[1, 2]` (modulo five)
-> `[1, 2]` (deduplicate; no change)
-> `"bb"` (index into "bbaac")

Comment: `Ø½p`3ṭịØaŒ!F=¥Þ⁸ṪṪ` saves two bytes for your brute force solution. I’ve taken a different approach that I’ll post separately.

Comment: Totally forgot to golf the magic table LOL.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->s{"%x"%(726-s.scan(/c|../).sum(&:hex))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664Wkm1QklVw9zITLdYrzg5MU9DP7lGT09fU6@4NFdDzSojtUJTs/Z/gUJatHpyYmJiUlKieixXgYJBRbK2QUViIohIAhJJIFZS0n8A)

`0xaa+0xab+0xba+0xbb+0xc` is 726.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>29</s> 23 bytes

```
$
¶aaabbbbac
D`c|..
1A`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU4xCoAwENvzDgWngk8QBL/R9HBwcRBH3@UD/NiZOz3KhaRJ2mM9t53eD0v1Ds9NsmlomKtdpWCcqruFxIYPDCaTDsRogc2kE7l/rjsw9RYYSfktHoBS0YBkwmjLgo9nIj/CFw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$
¶aaabbbbac
```

Append another copy of the whole list on a separate line.

```
D`c|..
```

Remove duplicate elements from the copy.

```
1A`
```

Remove the original input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 209 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{r,S:=ReplaceAll(s,"c",""),map[string]int{"aa":0,"ab":0,"ba":0,"bb":0}
for i:=0;i<len(r);i+=2{k:=r[i:i+2]
if S[k]<1{S[k]++}}
for k,v:=range S{if v<1{return k}}
return"c"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZLBattAEIaht-ylrzBZMEh4a9KcipwtBNprCbFvrgmzi2QWyWshrUPCoifJxQTyEHmMHtOn6axWInZ60ex--mf0z4yenje7w2uNusRNDls0lpltvWvcjBdbx1_2rvjy7e3PyFrXGLtpOSv2VkORtBBJGoNvxCKTt3ldoc6vqyppBddccJ6KLdarKFob6zxH5NmF4Kj6oOJNhVvHil0DJpMXc3NV5TZp0rmZyktfZrJZmcxML9fMFLBYleurrz6E6bSLWaW4JxFa6mXhSXNPgiZ3-8ZCSZJ4JEtdbOzvp8_usc5hGdrYawfe2FpA_lAPfXWx0TCXJAXPXN66FjIJq_XSM8-1UgqpBwGhoU4QikQfI43E1KkKEfWA1JioKRGPUQ_-V1FyQGqohX2i-oDUB5VCUkWraqhFFoKzY9RrTlHwPhrTY-J7RyMKGnWk6hi7oRG6yiZcSgmL5fXtEujE035Vd8KFQcZlxbl6doa6p0XiZrSKlJ3REndlQOENlXEz2s4czgl66D9QJHzSgvwO9EwmbQoT99uSjb6CCHkiZgmqlEJHzk6Mwc9fP2AwNvwXh0OM_wA)

#### Explanation

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{
// remove "c" from the input. guaranteed to be even length
r:=ReplaceAll(s,"c","")
// map to keep track of seen pairs
S:=map[string]int{"aa":0,"ab":0,"ba":0,"bb":0}
// for each pair of chars...
for i:=0;i<len(r);i+=2{
// get the pair
k:=r[i:i+2]
// if pair is not seen yet, increment the counter
if S[k]<1{S[k]++}}
// for each pair...
for k,v:=range S{
// if not seen, return that pair
if v<1{return k}}
// otherwise return "c"
return"c"}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

Two bytes saved by replacing `"ab"` with `⊝.`

```
⊔⊡⊗0⊐⊃∊'⊂⊙"c"∩(↯~2)⊞⊟.⊝.▽≠@c.
```

[Try it online!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=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)

Interestingly, since Uiua has an autoformatter that runs during execution, afterwards it is 30 bytes. (Specifically, `'⊂⊙"c"` is turned into `(⊂⊙"c")`)

### Explanation

```
                          ▽≠@c. # Remove all c from the string
                     ⊞⊟.⊝.      # construct "ab" and generate all pairs of its elements
               ∩(↯~2)           # Simultaneously:
                                  # flatten the table into an array of 2-char strings
                                  # chunk the input (sans c) into 2-char strings
     ⊐⊃∊                        # Both find which of aa,ab,ba,bb are in chunked input...
        '⊂⊙"c"                  # ...and add c to the array of aa,ab,ba,bb
  ⊗0                            # Index of pair that was not found (4 if all were found)
⊔⊡                              # Select from aa,ab,ba,bb,c
```

Comment: Is the `'` just syntax for *atop* (composition of two functions)? Can't find anything in the docs. Also I think `"ab"` can just be replaced by `.`. A bit less efficient, but that doesn't matter

Comment: @ovs For `'`, yes, though it's deprecated since 0.1.0.

Comment: @ovs I used cartesian product as a sort of shorthand; it's not actually a set operation. There's probably a better word, but it's not coming to me. In any case, it can't just be replaced with `.`. That does inspire a different length optimization, though!

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 27 bytes

```
?"c"⍜(-@a)(◿2/+↯~2▽<2.)=8⧻.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPyJjIuKNnCgtQGEpKOKXvzIvK-KGr34y4pa9PDIuKT044qe7LgoKZiAiY2JiYmFhYiIgICMgImFhIgpmICJiYmJhYWJjIiAgIyAiYWEiCmYgImNhYmJhYmIiICAjICJhYSIKZiAiYmFhYWNiYiIgICMgImFiIgpmICJiYmNhYWJhIiAgIyAiYWIiCmYgImNhYWJhYmIiICAjICJhYiIKZiAiYmJjYWJhYSIgICMgImJhIgpmICJhYmNhYWJiIiAgIyAiYmEiCmYgImFiY2JiYWEiICAjICJiYSIKZiAiYmFjYWFhYiIgICMgImJiIgpmICJhYWNhYmJhIiAgIyAiYmIiCmYgImNhYWFiYmEiICAjICJiYiIKZiAiYmJhYmFhYmEiICMgImMiCmYgImFhYWJiYWJiIiAjICJjIgpmICJhYmFhYmJiYSIgIyAiYyIK)

**Explanation:**

For the cases where 'c' is in the string, this uses a little trick by converting 'a' to 0 and 'b' to 1, then the XOR of the three pairs results in the missing pair.

```
?"c"                    =8⧻.   # If the string length is 8, return "c"
    ⍜(-@a)(           )       # Subtract char 'a' from the string to get an
                               # array where a=0, b=1, c=2. Then perform the
                               # following and add char 'a' back at the end:
                   ▽<2.        # Remove any 2s (char 'c')
                ↯~2            # Reshape to pairs
            ◿2/+               # XOR by adding the pairs and taking modulo 2
```

**Example:**

Input: "cbbbaab"

| Operation | Stack (top on left): |
| --- | --- |
|  | "cbbbaab" |
| `⧻.` | 7 "cbbbaab" |
| `=8` | 0 "cbbbaab" |
| `?"c"` | "cbbbaab" |
| `⍜(-@a)(` | [2 1 1 1 0 0 1] |
| `▽<2.` | [1 1 1 0 0 1] |
| `↯~2` | [[1 1] [1 0] [0 1]] |
| `/+` | [2 2] |
| `◿2` | [0 0] |
| `)` | "aa" |

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), <s>32</s>, 29 bytes

```perl
$_=s/c//?eval s/..\K\B/^/gr:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5BCsIwEIXhfU6RhSuhnZUbRQW3XqEo7w1FhGJLIx7fOEkbWpcf/yQzQzt2uxjE11uRQ9zcj0FU5Nx@0Pkgdd1cm4vc5DHuNUYlCdD76uQBN0kLFWYuFYAW0obVhlGY8V/tQSbhkIe5IleVsDqfQTpbkzYX5rYw3ZQXG9VNzX6elArn9u2H97N/hVh1ww8)

If `c` can't be removed returns `c` otherwise bitwise xor 2 char strings.

-3 bytes thanks to Kjetil S, changing `(?!$)` (negative lookahead end anchor) with `\B` (non-word-boundary)

Comment: Nice. Replace `(?!$)` with `\B` to save 3.

Comment: sure, thanks for seeing it

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (SE)](https://www.oracle.com/de/java/technologies/java-se-glance.html), 164 bytes

`b->{if(b.contains("c"))l:for(var c:"aa ab ba bb".split(" ")){for(int i=0;i<6;i+=2)if(c.contains(b.replace("c","").substring(i,i+2)))continue l;return c;}return"c";}`

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVE9T8MwEN3zK06eYoVaqANDQ1lYWGDpiBjuXBdcXCeynUqoym8PZycU8OD78Lvnd3dHPOPquP@c7KnvQoIjx2pI1qknjB87k9qq0g5jhGe0Hi4V8LE@mXBAbeBlyeSzS8H6d9D14kTZlrexKiYmTFZzhYctTLR6uNhDTUp3PjFzrIUWUrrNoQv1GQPojUAEJCAEIqFi72yqBTDokjGsAez2trX3d61ttmvJbPqXjVQwvWOJmfdGCKniQLEIq@2NbdZSygy2fjDg2mDSEDzodpw9LmrHqZ2V9wM5Vr40cO7sHk78ydLn6xug/DMGFgc/I0gmpkeMBjYgNBFh7qcYDRrZodwfos6WNOcRyr3EVEaQM5RtrmQ8x8zDVZkBSlSGlOHszHGpyB7h/@FdhZadfcVkTqobkupZcXK@vmpuQLDsxit9zcllpfNa53ucvgE)**

**Formatted:**

```java
    static Function<String, String> f1 = b -> {
        if (b.contains("c"))
            l:for (var c : "aa ab ba bb".split(" ")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
                    if (c.contains(b.replace("c", "").substring(i, i + 2)))
                        continue l;
                return c;
            }
        return "c";
    };
```

**Logs:**

- Golfing tips for I/O defaults respected (lambda function `b`) Thanks @corvus_192 !
- `String` replaced with `var` at one place (-3 bytes)
- `System.out.println`s replaced with `return`s (-31 bytes) Thanks @ceilingcat !
- `return "c";` replaced with `return"c";` (-1 byte)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms thank you. :) ... hope, the idea of the approach is understandable.

Comment: The variables b and p might also be inline => new length: 251 bytes.

Comment: Instead of the `continue l` thing, could you maybe `&&` the condition in the inner loop with a `bool` variable repeatedly, then `if` on that to `println(c)`?

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms It's longer then.

Comment: Welcome! We have a page dedicated to [golfing in tips in java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) (and many other languages). Also check out our [I/O defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). In most cases, you can submit a lambda function as the shortest way, like `b->{...}`

Comment: 196 bytes: `b->{if(b.contains("c"))l:for(var c:"aa ab ba bb".split(" ")){for(int i=0;i<6;i+=2)if(c.contains(b.replace("c","").substring(i,i+2)))continue l;System.out.println(c);}else System.out.println("c");}`

Comment: @corvus_192 Thanks for these hints! I will modify this later. However, keep in mind, that also a lambda function must be declared somewhere (for example with additional modifiers).

Comment: Yes, but our rules say only the lambda function (or any other expression that evaluates to a kind of function) has to be counted. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet and https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503 and https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
⌊⁻⪪”&∨O⊕”²⪪⁻Ｓc²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3My8ztzQXRJcWawQX5GSWaCglJiYmAUFispKOgpGmjgJEGKLEM6@gtCS4BKg5XQMopZSspAlSBATW//8nAXUmJyX91y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   ”...”        Compressed string `aaabbbbac`
  ⪪     ²       Split into pairs of characters
 ⁻              Remove elements from
           Ｓ    Input string
          ⁻ c   Remove the `c`
         ⪪   ²  Split into pairs of characters
⌊               Take the minimum
                Implicitly print
```

If all of the `a`/`b` pairs were successfully removed then the only remaining element is the trailing `c` otherwise the minimum element is the missing `a`/`b` pair.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 83 bytes

```python
lambda a:min({'aa','ab','bb','ba','c'}-{a.replace('c','')[i:i+2]for i in[0,2,4,6]})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZCxasMwEIbpWO3dhRZZ1A4hlFIM6Ut0dDz8J8dE4CjGcYYS8iRdDKV9p_ZpepZski4SH9-vu9N9fLfv_e7gh896vfk69XX28vPWYE8VJPK988lZAzrVID4oHCNafcnOWHTbtoHdJsyp1qZwuXtclfWhk046XyzTVfqUPpcXE0v_3j1Ua6WUJSKApMxeJSAi2RktmOlqAdgZicOWw5gxwH_LDwISBEKYbpBuLIHtNAaR4DZj5xmDu-I4U2jMaEV0XDnSaGhy_L_FsW1cn6iNV0bM25BVLu7bzvk-qRM3RUyxLM20nWGI9x8)

- -17 bytes thanks to Neil

Comment: `min(...)` is a byte shorter than `[*...][0]`.

Comment: ... which then allows you to port my Charcoal answer and replace `(a.replace('c','')+'c'*('c'in a))` with `a.replace('c','')`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->s{a=%w[aa ab ba bb c];a.find{[*(a-[_1]).permutation].join[s]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBNCsIwGAVx6ymCIqjQgjtBLK68RAjyXrRQwbb0BxHxJG6K6KH0NKZNq9K6CgzD8L5c70nOU3Hzl4888535c-V46RnL0VECAhSEIIVWC7h-EG7PcjqGIzczNXHjXXLIM2RBFCp3HwWhTNXlYjuv3joWvhxokgAHSgwdTwD9ilqoW1TDYHZcAPpL2RS0KaBFK_bXNZWasu6iKrBL2XUJ436uYN01u8rFLVqZHVpeZgeXVDeB5uJfWHr8mPY7i8K-bw)

Comment: Ruby, 56 bytes: [`->s{a=%w[aa ab ba bb c];s.scan(/[ab].|c/){a-=[$&]};a[0]}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZDNCoJAFEZp21MM9kMt1JaC6LKXGGbxfRdcRmQRYT5JG4l6qHqaRkcttNXA4czh3nt7HE68VPcseZ6OmR-9Ij_NCySLswYUqAhFKjFxHuSC3SrUoAmuEq4L-ImeL00ZQ29M6f6_J9u9yrQnJAF6Rs38VAHThjooAyqwmCMXgHwpu4LYAga0YX9dW2kp2y6aAseUY5ewbr8F266dq554QBtzROvN3MA1lS7QbfwLa4-96c5ZVe79AA)

Comment: [42 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA9CsJAEEax9RRLREiETSxtTOklQorvG0gpYgwi6klsguih9DTuTxIla7XwePuYmdtj3_DU3qv1szlUevVa6Lw-x_NjAShQEYpUUuo6rQXbOJNLmmZJUizLq__xnmx2qioiIQkwKtVM5wqYOuqhjKjAYAYuAPlS9gUxBYyoY39dU-kouy5cgSFl6BLGHbZg1zVz2YlH1JkBtZv5gS2VPtBv_Autx8H052xb_34A) by streamlining ValueInk's code.

Comment: Wow, your improvements make this so different that it's probably worth posting separately.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 82 bytes

```python
lambda a:("cbbaa"*469)[(k:=sum(map(ord,(r:=a.replace('c',''))+r[::2])))::k][r==a:]
```

An unnamed function that accepts the flattened, redacted permutation and returns the missing item.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU@9TsMwEN7zFIeX2BB1AITAklc2nqB0uKQONY1/dHYHFOXZg522KQM3WGd9f/eFn3Tw7uk10Nyrz3lA2@4RUHLWtS0iu39@eRNbfpQqniy3GLinfcNJKtyQDgN2mtdd3dS1EA@0lfJxJ4SQ8rjbklIod3NP3oJJmpL3QwRjg6cEQZM9JUzGu1hVASlFUMBZjmyAYVvedtnbZe@YqKreE1gTo3FfYBwsKllBnkDGJd6zjws6XmiTzLpCKNKSuej@ZHMezthqCKbPvzt1TcptFocySceUz6zrzbc3jhcjsYKk42kocM8L7wZgjLn9iq/ODfTsHc2g98sJY7GbZJaPRT@JbDWeRVMDzqdbK7Z6X4v/J7pUP1PE/As)**

A port of my non-brute-force [Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266575/53748).

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 80 bytes

`=substitute(regexreplace("aa|ab|ba|bb|c",regexreplace(A1,"(c|..)","$1|"),),"|",)`

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`.

Nothing clever here, just two replaces, plus removal of hardcoded separators.

Translation to JavaScript (90 bytes, non-competing):

```
s=>(r=(x,y,z)=>x.replace(RegExp(y,'g'),z||''))(r('aa#ab#ba#bb#c',r(s,'(c|..)','$1|')),'#')
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 73 bytes

```python
b,*l=0,{'c'},{0}
for c in input():l[b]^={c};b^=c<'c'
print(str(l)[3::10])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCoMwDEXf@xXii@3wQfFldOuXiEISHApFS9exDfHbu7QOQm5OknvdN8zb2l2dj@95sVPR6ukzkSzLMmJ9saap94qqo96bQzw2X1CxrFzuFaTStsdhNDsdNxwN3flROL@sQT6Dl1b1ndZtM6jIaSoSIgKgOIUEAQ/IDACUFIn3IHL/M98E5D0mTU7@Z@YcdqUEkYk1peWAk7MjTQg/)

**71 bytes**

```python
b=k=62
for c in input():k^=ord(c)*b;b^=c<'c'
print("babbaac"[k%7:][:2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzhCsIwDIT/9ylGQdb6zwkq1T7J2CCJk41JV8pEffqadELp5UvuLn7XcQnHS0z5PU7PoTq44TOQ0Vpn9LM/NeqxpIqqKfCLr9VYN/d@SXdDdo9X7D3daqpVTFNYjUZABCDdzruz61rXdDZzl82EckC1CSkSIzID20WReA@q/H/mm4KyR1FJsp@ZezglDaoQq7SVgo1LQiaEHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>31 30</sup> 29 bytes

```
(e.~{];,@{@;~@-.-._2<\-.)&'c'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxC8IwEIX3/IrDwSg0QRxblYLg5OSsyF1oURcXB6HQv14vyaVNHTJ8d@/x8u41LKxuYV@ChgI2UPIzFo6X82lYNbbvblVRd3XV18Yae9/ursaul9rpYa1U4x5vaEE7IkIkPQ4iu2ngkCfEikmCiI5mHscezD3472EJ@yYJBg/NBhQUWQ5L8r9xrP/MLCcOshwfk2uiZJ7kR9H2fX60VnIFAHMARCU3SCgXGLexfkRSUj6hVM@3bAhIqKR1hpRtpXBEUlI3oZRNmJp6dCq1FJKGgYYf)

*-1 thanks to ovs*

- `,@{@;~@-.` All valid 2 char pairs, constructed by the crossing the input with itself after removing 'c'.  This will contain dups but is guaranteed to have all the valid pairs.
- `-.` Minus
- `_2<\-.` All 2 char input pairs, formed after removing 'c'

  - At this point we will either have our answer or the empty list (in the case that 'c' itself is missing)
- `];` Prepend 'c'

  - Now we will have an answer that looks like `c;ab` (in the case we're missing a 2 char sequence) or simply `c` (in the case we're missing 'c')
- `e.~{` If 'c' is an element of the input, take the 2nd element.  Otherwise take the first (ie, return 'c' itself).

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
(-.~,&;(,{;~'ab')-._2<\-.)&'c'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxC8IwEIX3/IrDoddCE8SxVRfByclZkLtgURcXB0HoX6/X5NKmDhm@u/d4efccVg472DWAUMMaGnnWweF8Og6ldX1dtGX9bXskxsq662Z7sa4q0ONQGXPz9xd0gJ6ZSRTTILKfB55kwqKYJUTkeeHx4qHcQ/8ekYhvllDw8GLAQZHliCT/m8SOn1nkxEGWM8bkmihZJo2jaPs83ohGrwBg90Bk9AYJ9QLTNtaPyEbLJ9Tq@VYMAZmMts6Qs60WjshG6ybUsglT0xG9SS2VtGGg4Qc)

A similar alternate solution that has unboxed output and no conditional logic.  Feels slightly cleaner to me despite being 1 byte longer.

Comment: I think `(,{;~'ab')` can be replaced with the more inefficient `,@{@;~@-.` for -1

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 86 bytes

```python
lambda s:[*{'aa','ab','ba','bb'}-{*map(str.__add__,*[filter('c'.__ne__,s)]*2)},'c'][0]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDBasMwDEDZcf4K4x1sh6SMnkah-4xd0hAkp2aG1A2JdxilX7JLYGz_tH3NFDsh3cX205Ml2R_f3Xt4Pfvx0-4PX2_BFk8_Ly2csAE-7MrsIgFkLgFpwemEKK_FJTtBp4bQb-oamqau86y0rg3HXkkjKeiPFBt0lW31NadQVT5Wqfrv3UOzF0IYRARAzotnDsASmQUNEONqAcAsiJRsKBkWjPDf0oWICAxiMt4g3lgEsvMYiIzaTJ0XjG7FaabYmNCw5Khyosng7Oh9m6FrXVDi4IVm9txzx53nzY7dd73zQVnl5hRNf6NzvuK20umvxjHtfw)

No magic numbers here, just another approach to solving in Python, this one a straightforward-ish golfing of removing each of the pairs in the string (with `'c'` removed) from the initial set, and if none are left, defaulting to `'c'`.

Answer (score 3):

## Uiua, 38 characters (62 bytes)

`("c";|⊢▽¬∊,⊃(↯¯1_2▽∊,)(/⊂⊞⊂.)"ab")∊@c.`

[Uiuapad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=VGVzdERhdGEg4oaQIOKGr8KvMV8yIHJlZ2V4ICJcXHcrIiAkIGNiYmJhYWIgIC0-IGFhCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICQgYmJiYWFiYyAgLT4gYWEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJCBjYWJiYWJiICAtPiBhYQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAkIGJhYWFjYmIgIC0-IGFiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICQgYmJjYWFiYSAgLT4gYWIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJCBjYWFiYWJiICAtPiBhYgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAkIGJiY2FiYWEgIC0-IGJhCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICQgYWJjYWFiYiAgLT4gYmEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJCBhYmNiYmFhICAtPiBiYQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAkIGJhY2FhYWIgIC0-IGJiCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICQgYWFjYWJiYSAgLT4gYmIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJCBjYWFhYmJhICAtPiBiYgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAkIGJiYWJhYWJhIC0-IGMKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgJCBhYWFiYmFiYiAtPiBjCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICQgYWJhYWJiYmEgLT4gYwoKIyBTdGFjayBqdWdnbGluZwojIFNvbCDihpAgKCJjIjt84oqi4pa9wqziiLbiipniiIouL-KKguKKnuKKgi7iiLbihq_CrzFfMuKWveKIiiws4oi2ImFiIiniiIpAYy4KIyBVc2luZyBmb3JrIChzYW1lIG51bWJlciBvZiBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIGJ1dCBmZXdlciBieXRlcyB1c2luZyBVVEYtOCkKU29sIOKGkCAoImMiO3ziiqLilr3CrOKIiiziioMo4oavwq8xXzLilr3iiIosKSgv4oqC4oqe4oqCLikiYWIiKeKIikBjLgoKIyBUZXN0aW5nIGl0CuKJoSjijaQiV3Jvbmci4omNU29s4oip4oqU4o2Y4oqfKVRlc3REYXRhCgo=)

```
("c";|⊢▽¬∊,⊃(↯¯1_2▽∊,)(/⊂⊞⊂.)"ab")∊@c.­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
(    |                              )∊@c.  # ‎⁡Is 'c' a member of the string?
 "c";                                      # ‎⁢If not, just return 'c'
            ⊃            (/⊂⊞⊂.)"ab"       # ‎⁣Else, generate the list L = ["aa" "ab" "ba" "bb"]
            ⊃(↯¯1_2▽∊,)                   # ‎⁤And filter out any the c's from the string (by keeping only members of "ab") and reshape it into a n×2 matrix
      ⊢▽¬∊,                               # ‎⁢⁡Return the element of L which does not appear in this matrix.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'cK2ôH.«^12Mhl
```

Port of [*@Bubbler*'s J & Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266592/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPdnb6PAWD71Dq@MMjXwzcv7/T05KSkpMTAIA) or [verify all possible I/O test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/9WRvo8NbPPQOrY4zNPLNyPmvoxnzP1opOSkpKTExSUlHCcJIBrKSE4HMJLBYYmJiMoSVlAyUTQTLJsJkgWJAFUBWIlg2CcJKgoglJQLFwCYDzQCZCNELZYFsgBoIEYPqBrGBorEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'cK            '# Remove a potential "c" from the (implicit) input-string
   2ô           # Split it into pairs
     H          # Convert each string-pair from hexadecimal to a base-10 integer
      .«        # Reduce this list by:
        ^       #  Bitwise-XORing
         12     # Push 12
           M    # Push the largest value on the stack
            h   # Convert it from a base-10 integer to (uppercase) hexadecimal
             l  # Convert it to lowercase
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), <sup><s>67</s></sup> 64 bytes

```
patsplit($0,l,/c|[ab]./){$0="aaabbbbac";for(k in l)sub(l[k],a)}1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NCoMwEIX3cwoRFwbSaneFUug9xMXLgCCGVqoi9Ock3Qilh_I2nUkMIY83mffNfL6Yu2X5TWOzO66XHuPQ-3bMs9J6W_Crgqv3hXlm5TkF4OSA01Nzu-dd0l4Tb4bJ5b7qagvzPkTOhlvWB2s_HEVhYiHIJXFgVcdSB4V38_JHCHWnqknpZ51OklICBSeqtACIPiTClogr_AE)

Removed a semicolon by moving `patsplit` out to the pattern part (-1), and golfed the regex a bit (-2).

previous answer, 67 bytes:

```
{patsplit($0,l,/c|[ab]{2}/);$0="aaabbbbac";for(k in l)sub(l[k],a)}1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BCoMwEEX3cwoRFwoWbVcF6arHEBc_A4IYWqlKodaTdBMoPZS36UxiCPn8yfw38_ni2Tv3m6f2cN6uy4BpHGw3pUmZ27zgdw3TLKe1yKqkvMQAjBxwXLX3R9pH3S2y2Tib1NZ9kyNbjwG1E932Yu2HoSBMLAS5JA6saljqIP_uXv4Ivm5UNSn9rNNJUkog70SV5gHB-4TfEmGFPw)

- `patsplit($0,l,/c|[ab]{2}/)`: Split `$0` (the input string) into valid chunks and store as a list in `l`. `/c|../` doesn't work because regex matching is done in favor of longer length across all alternatives.
- `$0="aaabbbbac"`: Replace `$0` with this fixed string.
- `for(k in l)sub(l[k],a)`: For each chunk in `l`, find and remove once from `$0`. An uninitialized variable `a` is used in place of an empty string.
- `1`: An all-match pattern. This causes `$0` to be printed as a default action.

Replacing **without** splitting `"aaabbbbac"` into chunks first works because

- there is only one place to be replaced for `ab` and `ba`, and
- for `aa` and `bb`, it doesn't matter which part of the runs is removed.

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, <s>69</s>, <s>63</s>, 57 bytes.

A bit more golfing saves another 6 bytes.

Prompts for string:

```
((8=⍴i)/'c'),(~s∊⊂[2]((⍴v),2)⍴v←(i←⎕)~'c')/s←,'ab'∘.,'ab'
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEX3uUgSaC3WjRsPICgeQFzMRCqFgkJBcNOFCy0FxY3gQTxRLhJ/0qZukjd//vxPpyrdX6g6HlJTUV2Xxtnne72yt9dMgJYb0FTY9l44peYL@/iWOpNG6kQ1tW072123@U4pLM46ybX/caJKPLjXjfdmNaZEEkvbfiYBHCKFK4Q0zEwQBLhHE9gQBh50IjKR2cBDg4f@HujwBabg4cgcdSboQxcSfUPMGdm3jgW9Pib5yW9@)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) <sup>≤ [v2.21.12](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.21.12)</sup>, 14 bytes

```
\cẆǒf«H₴Ǐ3F«ǒ⊍
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFxj4bqGMnbhuodmwqtI4oK0x48zRsKrMuG6h+KKjSIsIiIsImNiYmJhYWJcbmNhYWJhYmJcbmFiY2JiYWFcbmJhY2FhYWJcbmFiYWFiYmJhIl0=) (code modified to work on current version)

I'm using an older version of Vyxal because for some reason `ǒ` was modified in a recent version. Also, yes there's another  Vyxal answer, but this one's shorter in regular SBCS bytes.

```
  Ẇ            # Split (keeping delimiter) on
\c             # "c"
   ǒf          # Cut each into chunks of length 2
     «H₴Ǐ3F«   # Compressed string "abaabbbac"
            ǒ  # Cut into chunks of length 2
             ⊍ # Take the set difference
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 12 bytes

```
ĕ<ĭÐŤʳXH"c"I
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FhuPTLU5svbwhKNLTm2O8FBKVvJcUpyUXAyVXXBzhlJyUlJSYmKSEpcShJEMZCUnAplJYLHExMRkCCspGSibCJZNhMkCxYAqgKxEsGwShJUEEUtKBIqBTQaaATIRohfKAtkANRAiBtUNYgNFIQ4EAA)

The `xor` trick is borrowed from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266592/9288) by [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler).

```
ĕ<ĭÐŤʳXH"c"I
ĕ                   Pick one char out from the input string
 <                  Check that all remaining chars are less than the picked char
                    If this does not fail, which means the input contains 'c':
  ĭÐ                    Uninterleave the remaining chars into a pair of strings
    Ť                   Transpose
     ʳX                 Reduce by xor (chars are converted to code points implicitly)
       H                Convert from code points
           I        Otherwise:
        "c"             Return "c"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 93 bytes

```cs
x=>"aa ab ba bb c".Split().Except(x.Replace("c","").Chunk(2).Select(z=>""+z[0]+z[1])).First()
```

Explanation

```cs
x =>                         // input string
   "aa ab ba bb c".Split()   // construct array with the four pairs + c
   .Except(                  // remove from it...
       x.Replace("c","")     // remove c from input
       .Chunk(2)             // split into chunks of size 2 (each chunk is a char[])
       .Select(              // transform each item
           z=>""+z[0]+z[1]   // convert char[] to string
       )
   ).First();                // first item remaining. this is c if all pairs were removed
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p1ToID)

Uses `.Chunk` which isn't supported on tio.run.

Answer (score 2):

## C# (without Implicit global usings), 241 bytes

```
var v=new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();int i=0;while(v.Count<4){if(args[0][i]=='c')v.Add("c");else{v.Add(args[0].Substring(i,2));i++;}i++;}foreach(var k in"aa|ab|ba|bb|c".Split('|'))if(!v.Contains(k))System.Console.WriteLine(k);
```

This is my first golf, and the language isn't very golfable... be indulgent :-)

I didn't find a online compiler which handle input arguments correctly ; so to test this, paste it in a Visual Studio .cs file.

Comment: You can use tio to simulate the arguments [like this](https://tio.run/##dZA9T8MwEIb3/gqTJbZarAqxuamEGFi6ZWCIMtjOpT3VOJXtpkJJfnuwCbAA0umk03Pvex/a32uPc99hQ1rqg0N7rGoi3dGzYe6lI31h4UbKdx/gjT93xoAO2FnPX8CCQ80P6MNuUe4pE2gDwWIrbic0QPsoudqwe2QDtjTZVtu6wroocp2znj81Dc10xgQYD8NSf3Xx8qoWW4qbBxad12sxfaa2cyD1iab9zgRtJuUo1ajkqNSoM15eDAaajzljcepdWsIGidbTM2M/p1jfGeCvDgMc0EJkYp5Wq5amg79fMURvpVJkExO/YQRS6r9ZhPofnUq6GAnOHw).

Comment: You can save a few bytes when you replace the list with an array and a counter for the length and use `?=:` instead of `if-else` [tio, 189 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5BT8QgFITv@yuQSyFdm8boRSQevHrrwUPDAZDuvixSA8jGlP72CnEPJmoyyUvmy8wbHa51gC3N8IomEqIHdxgFkv4Q6LIl6VHizpzRhdwJBi4i4P3e8p6dj2ANsQ@3dEmjbVvBa3DsxQiC80Y3j1jj@4vXDR/qu4ZA2@5vKCuHrdPsjdRHUn@dEDgsZZYqK5mVyhp3w7uFSJrcUAoTuUrd0@yiBBfIidLhM0TzVq0wW9O9eIjmGZwpjG3rbjeRH@PFUrqVqsIrZb9hAVLqv1mB@p@cqrmiCrcv)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Building on @bsoelch [185 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY6xTsMwFEX3foXxElspUYRgwVgdWNkyMEQeno1TnmqcyjZBqO63B1t0QAKkO92jc98z8dpEXJcZX8jEYgro96MiEPaRn9YFAlmktx/kQu6UmObA0CeCst862Qv3cCuwbfkyurZVsppjr0ZUUjam2VFD7y9dN7zr7x1WhO0Nr1sWzCurdw4EPQXIoLOGrHU2tBuODhNrcsM5Tuxq6R5nnwB9ZAfOh8@Y7Fut4uxs9xww2Sf0tjCxnjebif14XJ3KttY19MzFb1gAgPmbFWj@8XT1SipcvwA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 118 bytes

Adaptation of *Arnauld*'s first [JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266568/116582)

(this could probably be outgolfed with the new base-16 trick)

```java
s->{var r="";for(var e:("aaabbabbc"+s).split("(?<=\\G..|c)"))r=r.contains(e)?r.replace(e,""):r+e+" ";return r.trim();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZdNctNAEIXX5BRTs5LKiQ4QY7JkE1YsCYvuzphykH8YyS6okCU7qrgAHIBr5SJmfjRKQvS64vLC9qfuedP91CPf0IHObq4/H3d7bldipKWuM@9otTG3JyfGrDa980sSZy7DDya83vd@tflkltXwoavn4fe7eHHXUx9yXJrWLI7d2ZvbA3njF9bOl1tfxS/uvLJExBzeYmdd3XS7dtVXtrp4vbi6ets036W2de0XvpHtpg86usrVF77xbtcGGZU7tbY@9zM3s8bOvev3fmN8E7Ssq3p@d5xHIcNmBj2H7erauAO1e@pdkb0jT@vTshv3deekd9f100161@3b3ixM2yyrFJE2G/i3rnfrZrvvm124sm83VZUvbtyXPbVBdMl4Ye9//zD23N7/@WlsPUtpgvj7X3@NneWghxJOKF@HIgyqP3w05D91de6NediULSU9DeW1g8inVJgxjVyhwgSpxIUVyjCWKeVWKNbMacOiUCEcK3FhTGNqRNPColBcq1gKRTMnXZBGzTizxNSASjaHQnFmyU3CVKmV5GJh@kzzxG313FM0Op3tJB1cM01L9wAdujdJR6cDyjCW08wThWLNqYYkChXC6wqRkjl2CMZyqqVCca1Sa5XYpAvSqFmhMTWgks2hUNwjyU3CVKmV5GJh@kzzy5xe5iNPzdZxPk7TMh8RzbNmmpb5COhwz09SLk5HVNHMxemIZtdM0@J0RucQjE3dgZqTJrjfWAqsOfVAWVeIlMxCWLMQKT0SIqVHkpuEqVIrycVS6P@xL3Z6riIjpxOk5VRFdOgeI6fjzOVUnaTjfERU0TzOR0QH1zByukKHWcPgpMG1SprgftN2SYllUdYdnQ4ow9jsdIUqPcpOx7Gs1EpysRT6WPOrl9s83XliwbhPagXZHMeOT2KCDgMlc3kSE2Rz1ijOzOOZCugwaQQdBkrm0jtBNkfrMpFSK6ZxOgr6y4LXHacjojiWR58LehiDmZmUWg1lhnT0OaKPNOe/qXfHfw)

---

We concatenate the string of all possible values with the string parameter, so that the whole resulting string contains every value twice, except for the "missing" value which will only appear once.

Then we use a regex to split the whole string into either `pairs of characters`, or `the character "c" alone`.

We parse the resulting array, and in a string accumulator we add any unseen value (with a space separator) and remove every value already seen. At the end, the accumulator contains only the missing value, and lots of spaces that we trim.

Comment: Only test cases in which the inputs were mixed element by element and not by individual characters are relevant. But this (adopted) solution seems to work.

Comment: @Tobias321 I copied Arnauld's test cases. If i'm not mistaken, it contains only all possible permutations of `elements`, and not permutations of `individual characters` ? Or can you give me an example of such a case ?

Comment: It was just a note. It's true, your test cases also contain all relevant test cases.

Comment: Example: All permutations of "aa", "ab", "ba", "bb" and "c" (missing one string) versus all permutations of "aaabbabbc" (missing one string). Only the former is sought (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>123</strike> 120 bytes

```
a["aa"];a["ab"];a["ba"];a["bb"];{if(!sub(/c/,z))$0="c";else{for(i=1;i<6;i+=2)delete a[substr($0,i,2)];for(k in a)$0=k}}1
```

- -3 bytes, thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCoMwEEX3@QobXEQq@Fh0k/ol4uJOGiEoLVRLoeK3pzPRTc6cydyL7xQjeg3owQrpIJ1O4lsYzWX5kKlcVf6KIq877bT18@K38fU2oWtsuN9suHZt8fCzX32GngPL@jZ5XYayLQYrl1MWnhmkYNr3JkZHRACpA0458EDsAJyQHO@h0ns6/ymkPQklyffs3MMpaVDJmNKWCg5PCZkIfw)

---

Ungolfed :

```
a["aa"];a["ab"];a["ba"];a["bb"]
{
    if($0!~/c/)$0="c"
    else{
        sub(/c/,"",$0)
        for(i=1;i<6;i+=2) delete a[substr($0,i,2)]
        for(k in a)$0=k
    }
}
1
```

Comment: No need for 3rd parameter in `sub(/c/,z,$0)` as defaults to `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), <s>96</s> 65 characters

```
c=@set{c;}
??=@set{??;}
\Z=${aa;aa}${ab;ab}${ba;ba}${bb;bb}${c;c}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ echo -n 'aaabbac' | gema 'c=@set{c;};??=@set{??;};\Z=${aa;aa}${ab;ab}${ba;ba}${bb;bb}${c;c}'
bb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcexDYAwDETRnjnY4hSZORDNnRVRUZEu8uzGEdX/7@4PM70dbx/TEZvZ/2aF62z7JEFGVaCqIrQsQcsOj0ySEv0D) / [Try all test case online!](https://tio.run/##lVHBToNAED13v2Il2G0PDeqVEOrBgycTjwIxM8PWNlYgQBMT5NtxdhdbGuvBy868l/d23uwiNNsh17SHWsvVvWx1074SNDpaiFmiAAARSGWRQlSGIWQC0DAAlnEETRgyJjzT8EU0Mji6iF0wYSz@pWGnne7uAevCcwbPNZwXxoRjZp5tEk23cItNGJP4JxCp0@5u2MgYBR41SyGqele0G6m@5PXq9qaRF@odn2mhpHosqkPL9Vk3h71pHj4rTa3OuX16V0JsylrujIhP6fnd1fEzknXWe6HMSzGrrTvy/IXUtC3lykity@NpQVm1wZv@gKCpyTZSDRStG912FPYijl0fxwzSl8jvAEKAniuGgFwRQjQYMUSDKaR@UHLpCTH7x7Yc34YKAl8xDtK06D1mXXzTdaftXP7MChYySSa6KPpLmmVyPndvYJ7PJMzLQg/f)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 187 bytes

Short version:

```
func m(_ s: String)->String{var t:Set=["aa","ab","ba","bb","c"];let s=s.map({String($0)});var i=0;while i<s.count{var x=s[i];if x != "c"{i+=1;x+=s[i];};t.remove(x);i+=1};return t.first!}
```

Verbose version:

```
func m2(_ s: String) -> String {
    var t:Set = ["aa","ab","ba","bb","c"]
    let s = s.map({String($0)})
    var i = 0
    while i < s.count {
        var x = s[i]
        if x != "c" {
            i += 1
            x += s[i]
        }
        t.remove(x)
        i += 1
    }
    return t.first!
}
```